# Store the value of a variable used in 3 separate pages for use on a forth page

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

Below is the `get_context_update` method of a Django SessionWizardView which is used to return several variables including `display_image` to internal pages of a multi page form. But I am having trouble assigning the variables `five_image`, `six_image` and `seven_image` in such a way that they stick.

So on pages 5, 6 and 7, the user sees a different image (display_image) each time.

But on page 8, I want to show the user whichever three images they have previously seen all one one page.

So I want to store the value of `display_image` for steps 5, 6 and 7 and add them to my context.update

However none of my attempts have cracked it. In the below case no images are visible on page 8. I even understand the reason why is because `if self.steps.current == '5': (6 and 7)` do not equal 8. But if I make them == 8 then it just shows the same image for all three and then removes it form `path_one_images`

**So my question is:** How do I store the each of the values of `display_image` which is shown on page 5, 6 and 7 so I can show all three on page 8?

```
path_one_images = ['P1D1.jpg', 'P2D2.jpg', 'P3D3.jpg', 'P4D4.jpg', 'P5D5.jpg', 'P6D6.jpg', 'P7D7.jpg', 'P8D8.jpg', 'P9D9.jpg']

class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  

        if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15']:

            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)   

            if self.steps.current == '5':
                context['five_image'] = display_image

            if self.steps.current == '6':
                context['six_image'] = display_image

            if self.steps.current == '7':
                context['seven_image'] = display_image

            first_three = ['5','6','7']

            context.update({'display_image': display_image,
                            'first_three': first_three,
                             })

            path_one_images.remove(display_image)
        return context
```

The above is meant to return a separate value for each of the following in my HTML template

```
<img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{five_image}}"/>
<img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{six_image}}"/>
<img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{seven_image}}"/>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to store a tuple of shown images in the session and then accessing it later?  (i.e. request.session['images_shown'] = (...))

Comment: Why is there a stray `/` on `'P5D5.jpg/'` in your `path_one_images`? (PS, from the title I was hoping someone was writing a website in a combination of Python and Forth… :)

Comment: @abarnert A mistake I will correct.

Comment: @gorus No I havent thought of that. I will look into it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually solved my problem by reversing my logic. Rather than trying to make the output of `display_image` equal to another variable which I would then use I went the other way.

I used a separate variable for each image (`first_image`, `second_image`, `third_image`) that I removed from the list of images and then made display image take the value of that. This still left me with the original value which I could use later.

```
 class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      
        def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
            context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  

            if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16']:

                global first_image, second_image, third_image 

                if self.steps.current == '5':
                    first_image = random.choice(path_one_images)          
                    path_one_images.remove(first_image)
                    display_image = first_image
                    context['display_image'] = display_image

                if self.steps.current == '6':
                    second_image = random.choice(path_one_images)    
                    path_one_images.remove(second_image)
                    display_image = second_image
                    context['display_image'] = display_image

                if self.steps.current == '7':
                    third_image = random.choice(path_one_images)              
                    path_one_images.remove(third_image)
                    display_image = third_image
                    context['display_image'] = display_image   



                if self.steps.current == '8':
                    context['first_image'] = first_image
                    context['second_image'] = second_image
                    context['third_image'] = third_image   

                first_three = ['5','6','7']              

                context.update({'first_three': first_three
                                 }) 
            return context
```

Hopefully this might help somone